# Hide table border in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to hide the table border of  table within a Wordpress site. I already figured out, that my theme is setting the table border as standard and deleted the corresponding line of code.

My problem now is: The table border is still visible! Has someone of you guys a tip for me to solve this problem?

Here is a link to the website: http://studifutter.com/2732-2/

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,
Maverick

As requested, here you can see my current code:

```
<table style="border-color: #ffffff; background-color: #ffffff;" border="none">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h4>Über den Autor</h4>
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Vorname Nachname</strong> tempor cum
soluta nobis eleifend option congue
nihil imperdiet doming id quod
mazim placerat facer possim assum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
nonummy nibh euismod. soluta nobis
eleifend option liber tempor cum
solute.</td>
<td><img class=" wp-image-2548" src="http://studifutter.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Maske-300x225.jpg" alt="Häufiges Phänomen in Asien: Person mit Atemschutz. (Bild 2)" width="251" height="188" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I didnot found any border

Comment: I am wordpress guy,I can help you

Comment: Please have a look at the table near the footer of the site. The title is "Über den Autor".

Comment: Maybe try setting the border style to important in your custom CSS, border-style:none !important; It's hard to tell if you don't post the code you already have.

Comment: You do not have a border on that table. It is "visible" because of the difference in the white background of the table and the pale green background of the page. If you were to change the color of the border-color element to red or blue, you would see no change - because there is not a border set.

Comment: table tr td
{
 padding: 5px 5px;
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

Comment: just remove this , style="border-color: #ffffff; background-color: #ffffff;" border="none";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to hide table border then use:

```
.entry-content table {
    border: 0px;
}
```

If you need to hide table's TR border then use:

```
.entry-content table tr {
    border: 0px;
}
```

To Hide TD borders then use:

```
.entry-content table > thead > tr > th, 
.entry-content table > tbody > tr > th, 
.entry-content table > tfoot > tr > th, 
.entry-content table > thead > tr > td, 
.entry-content table > tbody > tr > td, 
.entry-content table > tfoot > tr > td {
    border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I see you have borders in your table tbody too. If you don't need border at all then you can use 


.entry-content table * {
 border: 0px !important;
}

Comment: Perfect! The code from your comment works. Thank you!

Comment: Remember that would remove all tables border inside entry-content div. I would suggest you to use specific classes for those tables that you don't want any borders. like, .entry-content .table-no-border * { border: 0px !important; }

Answer (score 1):

Under

```
<div class="clearfix entry-content">
```

You have a `table`.

To remove its border, you may add this to your CSS file at the bottom:

```
.entry-content table tr{
    border: none;
}
```